# Saving Preferences from a Dialog

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-dialog

After I open up a custom `Dialog` in my `Preferences` screen, how do I save to that specific preference after the `Dialog` goes away?

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.task_preferences);

        Preference dialogPreference = (Preference) findPreference(getString(R.string.clock_font_color));
        dialogPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener( new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                dialog(); ////How save here//????
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
  
  preferences.edit().putString("clockfontcolor", "-9856").commit();

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences(); 
preferences.edit().putString("clockfontcolor", "-9856").commit();
```